# Datatables table order with two rules

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter, datatables

I was making a table following the example from [here](http://mbahcoding.com/tutorial/php/codeigniter/codeigniter-ajax-crud-modal-server-side-validation.html) and I've got it all running except for one thing I cant figure out:

How can I order, and set the initial order of the table, using the values of the column "numeroregisto", when those values come as "XXX/YY" - I'd need it so that it orders the numbers on the right of the slash first, and then the ones on the left.
Numbers to the right are always two digits, the ones on the left can vary from one to five digits.

On another ocasion, using a different approach, I was told to do so as:

```
ORDER BY cast(substring_index(numeroregisto, '/', - 1) AS signed INTEGER), cast(substring_index(numeroregisto, '/', 1) AS signed INTEGER) ASC
```

But I cant seem to figure how to make that work with this approach:

```
var $table_registos = 'registos';
    var $column_order_registos = array('numeroregisto','dataregisto','amostra','especies.especie','requisitante',null); //set column field database for datatable orderable
    var $column_search_registos = array('registos.numeroregisto','registos.dataregisto','registos.amostra','especies.especie','requisitante'); //set column field database for datatable searchable just firstname , lastname , address are searchable
    var $order_registos = array('numeroregisto' => 'ASC'); // default order 


private function _get_datatables_query_registos()
    {
        $this->db->select('registos.*, origemmaterial.id AS omid, origemmaterial.origem, meioconservacao.id AS mcid, meioconservacao.meio, especies.id AS esid, especies.especie');
        $this->db->from('registos, origemmaterial, meioconservacao, especies');
        $this->db->where('registos.origemid=origemmaterial.id AND registos.meioid=meioconservacao.id AND registos.especieid=especies.id');


        $i_registos = 0;

        foreach ($this->column_search_registos as $item) // loop column 
        {
            if($_POST['search']['value']) // if datatable send POST for search
            {

                if($i_registos===0) // first loop
                {
                    $this->db->group_start(); // open bracket. query Where with OR clause better with bracket. because maybe can combine with other WHERE with AND.
                    $this->db->like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->db->or_like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                }

                if(count($this->column_search_registos) - 1 == $i_registos) //last loop
                    $this->db->group_end(); //close bracket
            }
            $i_registos++;
        }

        if(isset($_POST['order'])) // here order processing
        {
            $this->db->order_by($this->column_order_registos[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);
        } 
        else if(isset($this->order_registos))
        {
            $order_registos = $this->order_registos;
            $this->db->order_by(key($order_registos), $order_registos[key($order_registos)]);
        }
    }
```

Any help would be apreciated, much thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the problem with the current code? Can you pls narrow own the code to the part where you think the problem is?

Comment: I've edited the post to narrow it down as you suggested, think it should be clear now.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

issue resolved, and all by myself yeay!
just wish I could have come up with a more elegant solution:

```
private function _get_datatables_query_registos()
    {
        $this->db->select('registos.*, origemmaterial.id AS omid, origemmaterial.origem, meioconservacao.id AS mcid, meioconservacao.meio, especies.id AS esid, especies.especie');
        $this->db->from('registos, origemmaterial, meioconservacao, especies');
        $this->db->where('registos.origemid=origemmaterial.id AND registos.meioid=meioconservacao.id AND registos.especieid=especies.id');


        $i_registos = 0;

        foreach ($this->column_search_registos as $item) // loop column 
        {
            if($_POST['search']['value']) // if datatable send POST for search
            {

                if($i_registos===0) // first loop
                {
                    $this->db->group_start(); // open bracket. query Where with OR clause better with bracket. because maybe can combine with other WHERE with AND.
                    $this->db->like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->db->or_like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                }

                if(count($this->column_search_registos) - 1 == $i_registos) //last loop
                    $this->db->group_end(); //close bracket
            }
            $i_registos++;
        }

        if(isset($_POST['order'])) // here order processing
        {
            if($_POST['order']['0']['column']=='0' && $_POST['order']['0']['dir']=='asc'){

            $this->db->order_by('substring(numeroregisto,-2,2) ASC');


        }
        elseif($_POST['order']['0']['column']=='0' && $_POST['order']['0']['dir']=='desc'){

            $this->db->order_by('substring(numeroregisto,-2,2) DESC');


        }
            else{
            $this->db->order_by($this->column_order_registos[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);
            }
        } 
        else if(isset($this->order_registos))
        {
            $order_registos = $this->order_registos;
            $this->db->order_by('substring(numeroregisto,-2,2) ASC');
        }
    }
```